# WHERE clause on CASE Statement alias

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a CASE expression here that is adding a new column `IsAccountActive` with boolean values. How can I then add a where clause to only query for the rows that are active?

```
SELECT 
ma.CustomerID,
ma.FirstName,
ma.LastName,
(
    CASE WHEN (
        sa.Active < 1
            OR
        ma.Active < 1
            OR
        (sa.CancelDate IS NOT NULL AND sa.CancelDate <= GETDATE())
            OR
        (ma.CancelDate IS NOT NULL AND ma.CancelDate <= GETDATE())
            OR
        (sa.ExpireDate IS NOT NULL AND DATEADD(dd, sa.Extension + 1, sa.ExpireDate) <= GETDATE())
    ) THEN
        0
    ELSE
        1
    END
) as IsAccountActive
FROM MasterAccounts ma
INNER JOIN SubAccounts sa
ON sa.CustomerID = ma.CustomerID
INNER JOIN MasterAccountData mad
ON mad.CustomerID = sa.CustomerID
WHERE mad.AccountDataTypeID = 20001
AND mad.Data = ''
AND IsAccountActive = 1
```

Comment: is this MySQL or sql server?

Comment: If the latter, you can't reference the alias on a column anywhere but the `ORDER BY` within the same expression. You'll need to either repeat the expression, or use a CTE or a SubQuery in your `FROM`. I don't know if the same is true for MySQL, but I wouldn't be surprised if the same is true (or similar).

Comment: That's a `case` _expression_, not statement.

Comment: `ma.CancelDate IS NOT NULL` can be removed,  since `ma.CancelDate <= GETDATE()` will only be TRUE for non-null ma.CancelDate values.

Comment: SQL Server! Case expression, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WHERE clause does not have any idea about aliased in SELECT list.

**Reason:** There's a logical processing order in MS SQL server (**[see link here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement)**) and in it WHERE is computed before the SELECT list

So one way is to create an inner query and put where outside.

```
Select * from
(
SELECT 
ma.CustomerID,
ma.FirstName,
ma.LastName,
(
    CASE WHEN (
        sa.Active < 1
            OR
        ma.Active < 1
            OR
        (sa.CancelDate IS NOT NULL AND sa.CancelDate <= GETDATE())
            OR
        (ma.CancelDate IS NOT NULL AND ma.CancelDate <= GETDATE())
            OR
        (sa.ExpireDate IS NOT NULL AND DATEADD(dd, sa.Extension + 1, sa.ExpireDate) <= GETDATE())
    ) THEN
        0
    ELSE
        1
    END
) as IsAccountActive
FROM MasterAccounts ma
INNER JOIN SubAccounts sa
ON sa.CustomerID = ma.CustomerID
INNER JOIN MasterAccountData mad
ON mad.CustomerID = sa.CustomerID
WHERE mad.AccountDataTypeID = 20001
AND mad.Data = '')T
where T.IsAccountActive = 1
```

Another way is to put case in where clause like

```
SELECT 
    ma.CustomerID,
    ma.FirstName,
    ma.LastName
    FROM MasterAccounts ma
    INNER JOIN SubAccounts sa
    ON sa.CustomerID = ma.CustomerID
    INNER JOIN MasterAccountData mad
    ON mad.CustomerID = sa.CustomerID
    WHERE mad.AccountDataTypeID = 20001
    AND mad.Data = ''
    AND CASE WHEN (
            sa.Active < 1
                OR
            ma.Active < 1
                OR
            (sa.CancelDate IS NOT NULL AND sa.CancelDate <= GETDATE())
                OR
            (ma.CancelDate IS NOT NULL AND ma.CancelDate <= GETDATE())
                OR
            (sa.ExpireDate IS NOT NULL AND DATEADD(dd, sa.Extension + 1, sa.ExpireDate) <= GETDATE()))
         THEN
            0
        ELSE
            1 
        END =1
```

Comment: @MattLarson Missed a parenthesis. Added back.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your query up in a derived table (sub-query), then you can apply that condition on its result:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
    ma.CustomerID,
    ma.FirstName,
    ma.LastName,
    (
        CASE WHEN (
            sa.Active < 1
                OR
            ma.Active < 1
                OR
            (sa.CancelDate IS NOT NULL AND sa.CancelDate <= GETDATE())
                OR
            (ma.CancelDate IS NOT NULL AND ma.CancelDate <= GETDATE())
                OR
            (sa.ExpireDate IS NOT NULL AND DATEADD(dd, sa.Extension + 1, sa.ExpireDate) <= GETDATE())
        ) THEN
            0
        ELSE
            1
        END
    ) as IsAccountActive
    FROM MasterAccounts ma
    INNER JOIN SubAccounts sa
    ON sa.CustomerID = ma.CustomerID
    INNER JOIN MasterAccountData mad
    ON mad.CustomerID = sa.CustomerID
    WHERE mad.AccountDataTypeID = 20001
    AND mad.Data = ''
) dt
WHERE IsAccountActive = 1
```

Note that

```
(sa.CancelDate IS NOT NULL AND sa.CancelDate <= GETDATE())
```

can be simplified as

```
(sa.CancelDate <= GETDATE())
```

Comment: I'd hope the optimizer would absorb the IS NOT NULL into the <= automatically?